# Why do I get Status 400, Bad Request on my POST URL (using postman)

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to follow a Spring Boot Tutorials on youtube and I get stuck at Post.
I tried searching for fix but I can't find an specific answer why I can't access the post URL?

I tried both @PostMapping and @RequestMapping(Method = POST)
still same results.

Maybe I am accessing my URL wrong?
I am trying to Post at /api/sis/student_reg

need help, thanks!

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/sis")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

   @GetMapping(path = "/student")
   public List<Student> displayStudent(){
      return studentService.getStudent();
   }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/reg_student")
    public void registerStudent(@RequestBody Student student){
        studentService.addStudent(student);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class StudentService  {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    private Student students = new Student();

    public List<Student> getStudent(){
        List<Student> student = new ArrayList<>();
        studentRepository.findAll()
                .forEach(student::add);
                return student;
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student){
        studentRepository.save(student);
    }
```

```java
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {

    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "student_sequence",
            sequenceName = "student_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )

    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "student_sequence"
    )
    private String id;

    private String FirstName;

    private String LastName;

    private String email;



   // Method Converting UUID into string
    public String genID(){
       id = uuid.toString();
       return id;
    }
  
//Constructor, getters and setters
```

Edited again:
I receive error 400 when using the "Post" while 405 "Get" on the post URL.
apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Do you get any response body from the 400 Bad request that might indicate what went wrong? This is very useful information when trying to solve this problem.

Comment: "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "path": "/api/sis/reg_student" 

This is only showing on postman. apologies I am new to springboot.

when I tried it on my browser it has:
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).

Comment: Weird, in your question you posted that you received a `400 Bad Request` while now you're getting a `405 Method Not Allowed`. Can you verify that you're still using a POST-request in Postman?

Comment: Sorry the 400 was a mistake..I edited it now. I checked it again its 405 Method not Allowed.

Comment: Thanks for double checking. This should work (both with `@PostMapping` or `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)`. Do you have any other controllers that might interfere and did you check that you're really sending a POST-request in Postman?

Comment: I only have one controller. For Postman, I have selected the Post:http://localhost:8080/api/sis/reg_student 

and input data on Body/raw , am I doing the right thing in postman?

Answer (score -1):

It is not about wrong url. If that would have been the case you would get 404 Not Found error and not 400 i.e., Bad Request.
This means your request is not proper. Can you please also update the whole request body which you are using in postman and also attributes of your Student Class.

Comment: Hi! apologies for the 400, Its 405 I edited the title. 

I edited the post and include the student class too. 
I'm not quite sure about the "update the whole request body" part. I am new to spring boot.

Comment: 405 means METHOD NOT ALLOWED and you are getting this when you are making a GET request which is absolutely correct. Reason being, your student registration api is expecting HTTP method as POST and not GET.
Now, you are trying to make a POST request to /api/sis/student_reg but your REST api is exposed on /api/sis/reg_student as per your post. Please try making a request to correct api.